# Creating Msg & Srv issues

Tags: ros-kinetic, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am very new to ROS & Ubuntu and am working through the ROS tutorials.

Specifically, I am currently creating and customising my own packages (see link below for tutorial I am currently referencing.

http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv

I am using ROS Kinetic & Ubuntu16.04 LTS.

In section 2.1 I am trying to create a msg and edit the CMakeLists.txt file, but I am confused with some of the instructions.

I have opened CMakeLists.txt in my text editor but I am unsure where to add the following text.

So the instructions are as follows;

Open CMakeLists.txt in your favorite text editor (rosed from the previous tutorial is a good option).

Add the message_generation dependency to the find_package call which already exists in your CMakeLists.txt so that you can generate messages. You can do this by simply adding message_generation to the list of COMPONENTS such that it looks like this:

Do not just add this to your CMakeLists.txt, modify the existing text to add message_generation before the closing parenthesis

> find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS

> roscpp

> rospy

> std_msgs

> message_generation

> )

**I am unsure where to add this to the text file**

The instructions also state the following steps:

Also make sure you export the message runtime dependency.

catkin_package(
...
CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime ...
...)

Find the following block of code:

> add_message_files(

> FILES

> Message1.msg

> Message2.msg

> )

Uncomment it by removing the # symbols and then replace the stand in Message*.msg files with your .msg file, such that it looks like this:

> add_message_files(

> FILES

> Num.msg
> )

By adding the .msg files manually, we make sure that CMake knows when it has to reconfigure the project after you add other .msg files.

**I cannot find this in the text file**

If anyone could provide guidance I would very much appreciate it. Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I am very new to this.

I have attached a snap of the CMakeLists.txt file for reference.

[C:\fakepath\Page 1.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/15888526709592904.png)

[C:\fakepath\Page 2.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/15888526837770229.png)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351693/creating-msg-&-srv-issues/) by [jimc91](https://answers.ros.org/users/45049/jimc91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2020-05-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I cannot find this in the text file

That's because the `CMakeLists.txt` you show in your screenshots (and *please* do not post screenshots of text, just copy-paste it into your question next time) is the wrong `CMakeLists.txt`.

Your own package has a `CMakeLists.txt`, and you should be editing that file.

The file you show is a system provided file, which you should not need to edit for anything. In general: if the tutorials ask you to edit any files, it will be files which are in your own packages.

> If anyone could provide guidance I would very much appreciate it. Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I am very new to this.

It's a cliché, but there are no stupid questions.

We all had to start somewhere.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jimc91](https://answers.ros.org/users/45049/jimc91/) on 2020-05-07**:
I found the correct .txt file, thank you for your help.